Solving equations using implicit differentiation and differential equations
I appreciate this title sounds wrong.
I have a concept MCQ quiz which I give to students. One question asks "What is a differential equation?" One of the choices says:

taking an implicitly defined curve such as $x^2+y^3=1$ and finding
$\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

I am now updating these quizzes to include feedback to student answers and what I just realised is that when you do implicit differentiation with a relation $F(x,y)=0$ you actually generate a differential equation $G\left(x,y,\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=0$. I can see that going on to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is certainly not quite the business of "what is a differential equation", but I have:

In some sense, this isn’t a terrible answer. Indeed when you differentiate a relation you do get a differential equation. However not all differential equations are of this form (I think the ones that do are related to so-called “exact” differential equations (subquestion here!)). But in general, what you are doing  in an implicit differentiation is not finding $y=f(x)$ (like a differential equation), but rather finding $\frac{dy}{dx} = F(x,y)$.

This then piqued an idle curiosity.
Take a relation $F(x,y)=0$. In general we cannot solve $y=f(x)$ (because the relation does not define a function). However, if $F(x,y)=0$ does define a function maybe it is still extremely difficult to solve for $y=f(x)$.
QUESTION: I wonder is there such a relation that does define a function, $F(x,y)=0$ is extremely difficult to solve for $y=f(x)$, but if you implicitly differentiate to $G(x,y,dy/dx)=0$, solving THAT differential equation for $y=f(x)$ is not as difficult.
Or is this in a certain sense going to only happen in pathological cases?

Hi man can you just rephrase your question precising which relation define which fonction ? Otherwise if I anyway understand well, what you ask is from $F(x,y)=0$ equation, you want to deduce a $y=f(x)$ equation.

@EDX yes, via an implicit differentiation and then solving an ode. It is a general question looking for a relation that is easier to solve this way vs a direct solving of the relation for $y$. I don't know what is to rephrase.

I add an answer implying the implicit function theorem. It is not solely powerful but raises the limits of explicit expression by the gravitating examples and uses around you can further find on a research.

You are looking for solutions in closed form.
$$F(x,y)=0\tag{1}$$
Let
$A$ a nonconstant bivariate $\mathbb{C}$-algebraic branch of a relation, without a univariate factor over $\mathbb{C}$,
$f$ a nonconstant univariate $\mathbb{C}$-transcendental branch of a relation,
$$f(A(x,y))=0.\tag{2}$$
Because $A$ is $\mathbb{C}$-algebraic and doesn't have a univariate factor over $\mathbb{C}$ and the variables $x,y$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebraically independent, we don't know how to solve equation (2) for $y$ by rearranging by applying only finite numbers of elementary functions. Some nonelementary Special functions are needed.
If $f^{-1}$ is known and $f^{-1}(0)$ is an algebraic number, the analog holds for $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic $A$.
Differentiating equation (1) regarding $x$, we get
$$F_1(x,y)+F_2(x,y)\ y'(x)=0.\tag{3}$$
Differential algebra gives some methods to decide which kinds of equation (3) are solvable in closed form.

This may not be the answer that you are looking for, but there is a sense in which you're question is what underlies the Implicit Function Theorem:
If $F\colon \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ is a function, the locus $Z=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m: F(x,y)=0\}$ imposes $n$ contraints on points in $n+m$-dimensional space, so heuristically speaking should describe some $m$-dimensional analogue of a surface.  If at some point $(x_0,y_0)\in Z$ the partial derivative $\partial F_x(x_0,y_0)$ (i.e. the matrix $(\partial_{x_i} f_j)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ is continuous and invertible, then near $(x_0,y_0)$, $Z$ can be described as the graph of a function $f$, that is, near $(x_0,y_0)$ if $(x,y) \in Z$ then $y =f(x)$, and that function is continuously differentiable wherever $F$ is.
The theorem asserts the (local) existence and uniqueness of the function $f$, but finding it explicitly is, in general, difficult. On the other hand, using the chain rule it is straight-forward to check that $Df_x = -\partial_x F^{-1}(x,f(x))\partial_y F(x,f(x))$. One way to view the Implicit Function Theorem is therefore as the assertion that this system of differential equations always as a unique solution, at least locally, provided that the linearized problem at $(x_0,y_0)$ has a solution, which is exactly what the condition that $\partial_x F(x_0,y_0)$ is invertible ensures. That is, imposing smoothness conditions on $F(x,y)$ allows you to translate the problem of solving  $F(x,y)=0$ for $y$ in terms of $x$ into a differential equation, and although this may be just as hard to find closed-form solutions to, the implicit function theorem says that the local existence and uniqueness of a solution is  controlled by the linearised problem the derivative gives you.

The question is about the existence of relations such that solving the generated ode for a closed form isn't actually "just as hard" but in fact easier.

A track of answer can lie in implicit function theorem.

Theorem If there exists a $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (at least) function called $F$, such that $F(x,y)=0$ and there exists $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $\partial_yF(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$ then :
There exists a a $f$ a real function and an open neighbourhood of the point $(x_0,y_0)$ in which there exists the relation $y=f(x)$.

The proof lies in differentiating $F$ and apply Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem. I won't copy it here it is easy to find.
Yet the important point is to know if we can get a closed explicit form of $f$. The answer is generally no.
Yet you can have an expansion of $f$ around $x_0$ because :
$$ f(x_0+h) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h +o(h) $$
and the theorem's proof gives the following useful relationship :
$$ f'(x_0) = - \dfrac{\partial_x F}{\partial_y F}(x_0,y_0) $$

Thank you but this is not an answer to the question.
